# D3 line graph mouseover issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying on the d3 mouseover function on the graph to display the text value of timestamp and agv mileage but the circle keep sticking on top of y-axis and the graph will disappear when the mouse arrow pointed to inside and outside the area of graph.

`The code and output of the mouseover function are presented here` [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rW3ecb2kL9qngTeh3zxd?p=preview)

Anyone can guide me on this? your help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the bisectDate function and set the cx and cy attributes of the circle to make it move.

```
var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.Timestamp; }).right;
function mousemove() {  


    var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(focus.node())[0]),              
        i = bisectDate(dataset, x0, 1),                   
        d0 = dataset[i - 1],                              
        d1 = dataset[i];

        var d = x0 - d0.Timestamp > d1.Timestamp - x0 ? d1 : d0;     

    focus.selectAll("circle.y")
        .attr("cx", x(d.Timestamp))
        .attr("cy", y(d.AGV_Mileage))


}
```

Edited your [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pHHppMIN0A0NeP5oc1ps?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for your guidance, much appreciated! but when mouse pointed to the area of graph ( outside the x and y axis(nearby the area of graph) and on the area of graph) then the whole graph will disappear.

Comment: There was a line telling to "display: none" on mouseout. Edited again.

Comment: I made a similar viz with a different approach on [this site](https://www.rtup.unipg.it/SGrtup/Statistiche/SopravvivenzaMainPage.php). Check if you want

Comment: sure and sorry to bother you once again,one last issue, how to place the timestamp and mileage value beside the circle like you did on your site? my text appeared on the first value of x-axis(beside 11am)  instead of beside the circle. Below is the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/P5PGxbaMmgBfo7hdJ5VV?p=preview

Comment: You need to add a class or an id to select the correct text you want to change, otherwise d3 will select the first text element in the container. Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/E3dlJf9Bp8iUXQ4ktYfP?p=preview)